# ffmpeg: packet size 2073600 < expected frame_size 4147200

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have total 96 videos. I have converted most of videos using ffmpeg, 
but for some videos its giving me some error. 
As a first step I deinterlaced the video using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -r 25 -pixel_format yuv422p -i stockholm.yuv -vf yadif  stockholm_deInt.yuv
```

And I am getting the following error:

> [rawvideo @ 0x7fa144008c00] Invalid buffer size, packet size 2073600 < expected frame_size 4147200
>   Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
>   frame=  187 fps=3.7 q=-0.0 Lsize=  757350kB time=00:00:07.48 bitrate=829440.0kbits/s
>   video:757350kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%

When I try to get the info about the video (`ffprobe stockholm.yuv`) I get the following:

> [IMGUTILS @ 0x7fff5bac8140] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
>   [IMGUTILS @ 0x7fff5bac8150] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
>   [rawvideo @ 0x7fbcb200da00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, -4 kb/s): unspecified size
>   Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
>   stockholm.yuv: Operation not permitted`

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is quite offtopic, as it is not on programming but on how to use a software. See the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to learn which kind of question StackOverflow is meant for...

Comment: Could be a superuser.com question

Answer (score 2):

I think the pixel_format could be wrong. The error could be happening at the last frame of the input file. Due to **yuv422p** format, it expects "4147200" pixels(bytes) for every frame. If input format is wrong, it would end be reading lesser bytes at the end of file.

Did you try the same command with **yuv420p**, for same input file?

I suggest you to cross-check the format of input yuv file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to streaming at 1080p , changing my setting from yuyv422 to yuv420p fixed my issue.